# When to use - Delayed Job vs RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, sidekiq, delayed-job, task-queue

Can someone give me the clarity of the advantages of using RabbitMQ(message queue) instead of Delayed Job(background processing) ?

Basically I want to know when to use background processing and messaging queue ?

My web application has 3 components one main server which will handle all user requests and 2 app servers where all the background jobs(like es reindex, es record update, sending emails, crons) should be run.

I saw articles which say Database as a queue(delayed job) is very bad as the consumers will be polling the database for new jobs and updating the statuses of jobs which will lock the tables. Then how does rabbit MQ or other messaging queues store to avoid this problem.

There are other alternatives for delayed job like sidekiq which will run over redis instead of mysql. It is better to use sidekiq instead of rabbitmq?

And are there any advantages of using sidekiq over delayed job?

Comment: First FAQ: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: you are right databases can make jobs slow. even sidekiq has to make 3 roundtrips to Redis for each job. check this out http://sneakers.io/

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 workers and 1 web server: I guess your web app dispatches some delayed jobs to your workers. So you need *a way to store the data related to those background jobs*.

For that, you can use both a database (like Redis, this is what sidekick is doing) or a message queue (like RabbitMQ). A message queue is a specialized system that is very efficient for this use case (allowing a much higher throughput). A database would let you have a better introspection (as you can request the jobs table to see what your current situation is), while the queuing system would be more efficient but also is more a black box and will require new skills.

If you do not have performance issues, the simpler the better, even a simple mysql database should be enough. If you want a more powerful system or need a lot of monitoring you can also consider using a specialized hosted service such as [zenaton](https://zenaton.com) (I'm founder) that will do all the heavy lifting for you, including scheduling or more sophisticated orchestration of your background jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Both perform the same task, i.e executing jobs in the background, but go about it differently.

With **delayed job** one uses some sort of a database for storage, queries for the jobs thereafter then processes them. It's simple to set up but the performance and scalability aren't great.

**RabbitMQ** or its alternatives *Redis e.t.c* are harder to set up but their performance, flexibility and scalability is great, we are talking in the upwards of 5000 jobs per second besides you have tend to use less code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use task orchestration system like [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/). It supports both delayed execution and queueing, but provides higher level programming model and tons of features that neither queues or delayed execution frameworks.

Cadence offers a lot of advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Built in distributed CRON

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.